# How to start search `/` from a mapping?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, search

I'm trying to do the following mapping in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <silent> / :call <SID>FooFunction()<CR><BAR>norm! /
```

But when I press `/`, instead of running the function and then starting the search prompt, I get this text inserted to my buffer:

```
rm! /
```

I also tried to put the normal command to as the last line of `FooFunction`:

```
function! s:FooFunction() abort
    ...
    ...
    norm! /
endfunction
```

but then I don't get any prompt after pressing `/`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the the `<silent>` was hiding the search prompt, and also the mapping can be done just like this:

```
nnoremap / :call <SID>FooFunction()<CR>/
```

Comment: You could have used autocmds

Answer (score 3):

It seems you've already found a working solution, but I wanted to address the issues with your attempted approaches.

> But when I press `/`, instead of running the function and then starting the search prompt, I get this text inserted to my buffer:
>
> ```
> rm! /
> ```

You're getting this result because you're using `<BAR>` in your mapping *after* you already left command-line mode:

```
:call <SID>FooFunction()<CR><BAR>norm! /
```

You're using a `<CR>`, which means you're back in normal mode, so `<BAR>norm! /` (or, equivalent, `|norm! /`) is evaluated as a series of normal mode commands.

Command `|` moves to a column based on count, without a count, it moves to first column. `n` repeats the last search. `o` inserts a new line below the current line and starts insert mode. As you're now in insert mode, the rest of the mapping, `rm! /`, gets inserted as text.

Removing the `<CR>` would fix that part of the issue, however that'd be equivalent to your second approach, which doesn't work either, let's take a look:

> I also tried to put the normal command to as the last line of `FooFunction`:
>
> ```
> function! s:FooFunction() abort
>     ...
>     ...
>     norm! /
> endfunction
> ```
>
> but then I don't get any prompt after pressing `/`.

That's because the `norm!` command expects to execute a complete command, it doesn't allow for a prompt to be pending at the end of its execution.

From `:help :normal`:

> `{commands}` should be a complete command.  If `{commands}` does not finish a command, the last one will be aborted as if `<Esc>` or `<C-C>` was typed.

So `:norm! /` doesn't work, the search gets cancelled as the command completes.

An alternative you can use in a function is to call `feedkeys()`, which doesn't exhibit this behavior. For example, this would have worked:

```
function! s:FooFunction() abort
    ...
    ...
    call feedkeys('/')
endfunction
```

But, as you've noticed, an even easier approach is to simply use `/` directly in your mapping:

```
nnoremap / :call <SID>FooFunction()<CR>/
```